# Gas estimation errored

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, gas, error, bsc

When trying to deploy a contract, an error appears: "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error."  I would be very grateful if someone can help me deploy the contract and understand what the problem is. Below is the code of the entire contract

```
library Address {
   
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
 assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
 return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }
function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

     (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
    
    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
      return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value) internal returns (bytes memory) {
      return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, errorMessage);
    }

    function _functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 weiValue, string memory errorMessage) private returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");

    
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{ value: weiValue }(data);
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
           
            if (returndata.length > 0) {  
            assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;
    address private _previousOwner;
    uint256 private _lockTime;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor () internal {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

  
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

   
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }

    function getUnlockTime() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _lockTime;
    }

    //Locks the contract for owner for the amount of time provided
    function lock(uint256 time) public virtual onlyOwner {
        _previousOwner = _owner;
        _owner = address(0);
        _lockTime = now + time;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
    }
     function unlock() public virtual {
        require(_previousOwner == msg.sender, "You don't have permission to unlock");
        require(now > _lockTime , "Contract is locked until 7 days");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, _previousOwner);
        _owner = _previousOwner;
    }
}

// pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

interface IPancakeFactory {
    event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

    function feeTo() external view returns (address);
    function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

    function setFeeTo(address) external;
    function setFeeToSetter(address) external;

  function INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH() external view returns (bytes32);
}

// pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

interface IPancakePair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);

    function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;

    function initialize(address, address) external;
}

// pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IPancakeRouter01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

// pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IPancakeRouter02 is IPancakeRouter01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}
contract MyToken is Context, IBEP20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;

    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000000 * 10**9;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

    string private _name = "MyToken";
    string private _symbol = "MTK";
    uint8 private _decimals = 9;
    
    uint256 public _taxFee = 5;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 5;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

    IPancakeRouter02 public immutable pancakeRouter;
    address public immutable pancakePair;
    
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 5000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 500000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    
    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiquidity
    );
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
    
    constructor () public {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        // PancakeSwap Router address: (BSC testnet) 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1  (BSC mainnet) V2 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
        IPancakeRouter02 _pancakeRouter = IPancakeRouter02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
   
        pancakePair = IPancakeFactory(_pancakeRouter.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _pancakeRouter.WETH());

        pancakeRouter = _pancakeRouter;
        address payable _pancakeFactory = 0x3328C0fE37E8ACa9763286630A9C33c23F0fAd1A;

        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[_pancakeFactory] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() external view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) external virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) external virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function isExcludedFromReward(address account) external view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }

    function totalFees() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }

    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) external {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) external view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
        // require(account != 0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F, 'We can not exclude Pancakeswap router.');
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }

    function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is not excluded");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }
    
    function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _taxFee = taxFee;
    }
    
    function setLiquidityFeePercent(uint256 liquidityFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
    }

    function setMaxTxPercent(uint256 maxTxPercent) external onlyOwner() {
        _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(maxTxPercent).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }
    
    
    receive() external payable {}
    
  
    function rescueBNBFromContract() external onlyOwner {
        address payable _owner = _msgSender();
        _owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
    
    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
        if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
            _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
    }
    
    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }
    
    function removeAllFee() private {
        if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;
        
        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        
        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
    }
    
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
    }
    
    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        if(from != owner() && to != owner())
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");

       
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
        {
            contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
        }
        
        bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
        if (
            overMinTokenBalance &&
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            from != pancakePair &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled
        ) {
            contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
            //add liquidity
            swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
        }
        
        //indicates if fee should be deducted from transfer
        bool takeFee = true;
        
        //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
        
           _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
    }

    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);

       uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        swapTokensForBNB(half); // <- this breaks the BNB -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered
   
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

       
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }

    function swapTokensForBNB(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the pancakeswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pancakeRouter.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(pancakeRouter), tokenAmount);

       
        pancakeRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
  
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 bnbAmount) private {
      
        _approve(address(this), address(pancakeRouter), tokenAmount);

        pancakeRouter.addLiquidityETH{value: bnbAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
        if(!takeFee)
            removeAllFee();
        
        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
        
        if(!takeFee)
            restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is likely in the constructor. Did you try what is wrong with it? The first thing I'd try is commenting out lines until it works. Then uncommenting them until it fails, so you will have the faulty line. If you comment out everything and it still fail then the problem is in the tooling like are you deploying to the right network?

Comment: good day!  already tried to comment, nothing changes.  Trying to deploy on a Binance testnet using injected web3

Comment: if necessary, I have uploaded the full code to the github (here it is cut off).  https://github.com/bipolaraius/MyTokenDeflationBep20

Comment: Which line causes the error? Did you try commenting out the whole constructor? it should deploy. Did you deploying to ganache fork of bsc?

Comment: the error appears exactly when I try to deploy.  Errors are not shown in the code.  Can you tell me how to comment correctly? I'm trying to deploy using metamask

Comment: You can comment a line with `//` in front or enclose several lines with `/* code that you want to comment out */`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change BNB with ETH and WBNB with WETH:

https://pastebin.com/C0TDW440

Comment: Hi. If this actually answer the question, provide more information.